# Socket class is not working on Flex SDK 4.5

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sockets, networking, sdk

I am migrating an application from flex sdk 3.4 to flex sdk 4.5.

I am using a telnet example of AS3 tutorials as base to construct a generic socket class that implement a specific protocol.

The main problem is that the new application with the validated socket class does not fire any event (no error - no connected - no data - nothing). The try catch with the connect method  does not throw any error. I checked if the events were successfully connected, but they are not fired never.

**Update:** I used the suggestions to modidy the code. Actually, now I am receiving  an error on the security policy.

This is the constructor:

```
         public function GenericSocket(server:String, port:int, output:TextArea) {
            // set class variables to the values passed to the constructor.
            serverURL = server;
            portNumber = port;
            ta = output;

            // Create a new Socket object and assign event listeners.
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, connectHandler);
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, closeHandler);
            socket.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
            socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
                    //Added by suggestions
                    socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, dataHandler);

            // Load policy file from remote server.
            Security.loadPolicyFile("http://" + serverURL + "/crossdomain.xml");
            // Attempt to connect to remote socket server.
            try {
                msg("Trying to connect to " + serverURL + ":" + portNumber + "\n");
                socket.connect(serverURL, portNumber);
            } catch (error:Error) {
                /*
                Unable to connect to remote server, display error 
                message and close connection.
                */
                msg(error.message + "\n");
                socket.close();
            }
        }
```

This is the connectHandler, securityErrorHandler and the ioErrorHandler (Never called **Update:** Security handler is beign called)

```
        private function connectHandler(event:Event):void {
            if (socket.connected) {
                msg("connected...\n");
            } else {
                msg("Error: unable to connect\n");
            }
        }

//Added by suggestions

private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            msg("securityErrorHandler: " + event+"\n");
        }

        public function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            msg("Error: Unable to connect: socket error.\n");
        }
```

Some idea or directive could be useful. Maybe some test to try the generic socket? maybe the type of the application?

**Update:**
The error that I received is:

*securityErrorHandler: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]*

I am using these includes in the project:

```
           xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx2="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
```

Comment: Hi, 1) Is your code still working if you use sdk 3.4 ? 2) Flash socket security changed a lot since FP 10.0. A crossdomain-policy file is not enough anymore. 3) I see there is no SECURITY_ERROR_HANDER. It may be also a security error which you do not handle....          Also, I suggest you get a SDK 4.5 socket example from somewhere and test it with your socket destination and try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You should add `SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR` handler and be sure that you are not connecting to port lower than 1024, see Adobe reference - [http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html#event:securityError]

Comment: Hi, you are right, the security error hander was missed. I added the event and I received an error:
securityErrorHandler: [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678058/security-sandbox-violation-lack-of-policy-file-permissions/5678960#5678960) you can find an answer I gave some time ago to the same problem you have. Be sure to read the comments and follow the links, there is a good example/tutorial on one of the links. It's basically related to the way you serve the security policy, you have to serve it via socket after the app has sent a request for it on port 843. For this, you need of course a sever app, can't be served by a the webserver via HTTP.

Comment: I put a python server on the server side. As mindnoise wrote, "you have to serve it via socket after the app has sent a request for it on port 843. For this, you need of course a sever app, can't be served by a the webserver via HTTP." With this, the socket class works immediately.