# Security Sandbox Violation, can't connect to Server via Socket

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, sockets, cross-domain

Before I start I should state I have read it all, I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678058/security-sandbox-violation-lack-of-policy-file-permissions/5678960#5678960), [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html) and [this](http://haxe.org/forum/thread/2260) (and more...) and still I cannot connect to our running server via Socket over the internet.

Here is what I try to in AS3:

```
        var host :String = "192.168.2.11";
        Security.allowDomain(host);
        Security.allowInsecureDomain(host);
        Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + host + ":" +  "843");

        // TTS server socket
        _socket = new Socket();
        _socket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, handleClose);
        _socket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);
        _socket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleSecError);
        _socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, handleIncomingData);
        _socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, handleConnect);
        _socket.connect(host, 1337);
```

As you can see, the host is a local address, but that shouldn't matter as long as I am in this local network. And I am, since this does work from my IDE (FD4).
Also, the swf is on the same server as the application it tries to connect to, but on another port.

The policy file the server sends (we have tried both from port 843 and 1337) is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" /> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

We can see from the log output of the server that this is really sent to the connecting socket. A null byte is of course sent after the xml data. And after that, the server closes the connection. However, it seems that Flash somehow does not like it, as "Error #2048" still appears after ~3 seconds.

We're really out of ideas here...

Comment: port 843 is reserved for a master policy instead use the port 1337 that you are connecting to and dish out the file on the socket you are connecting to. Get rid of the Security.allowInsecureDomain line this is for https connections. And what language is on the server side.

Comment: here is the policy I use ( added some extra slashes so it would format)  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http:////www.w3.org//2001//XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http:////www.adobe.com//xml//schemas//PolicyFileSocket.xsd"><allow-access-from domain="\*" to-ports="\*"  /></cross-domain-policy>

Comment: Hey, thanks, we ended up implementing the  master policy file. The problem was that the xml that was sent back by the server did not include the "<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>" tag. And to answer your question, we use C/C++ on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We managed to get it to work by including another tag:

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
```

It seems that this tag is necessary in order to get it to work. We could not get it to work without that tag, no matter which port we tried.

So the complete xml now looks like this in our case (it is of course easy to modify to fit any case):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

It really is a shame that this line is not included in [Adobe's own example (!!)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html). I mean, it IS included in the example files, but **not in the article**. I don't want to know how many people were stuck at this stage because of that...

Comment: by doing it this way you are opening up all ports and all domains to your SWF files. Not very secure.

Comment: This is a test in our company, local network only. Security really is not important in this case ;) But yeah, in any production release it would of course be mandatory to limit domains and ports.